# Mongoose How to update if exists, based on custom fields. Otherwise insert

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm building a mongoDB database that holds sales data from multiple different systems. Each system is integrated via an node/mongoose/Express API that I'm creating for the database. Typically, you'd check the id to determine if a record already exists, and insert it if it doesn't. But since the ID from these different sources could technically overlap, I need a system to make sure that a source can only update records that originally came from that source. So I've added a column called "external_ID" where the record id from the source is saved, and another column called "integration ID", which will be unique to the specific system that sends data. But for that idea to work, I'd need to update only if those two columns matches, and otherwise insert a new record. Is that possible with MongoDB, or am I approaching this wrong?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `upsert` on `update()`. It will creates a new document when no document matches the query criteria.

```
db.collection.update(<query>, <update>, { upsert: true })
```

You can find more detail at [Upsert Behavior](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-option) documentation